# Converting List to Tupled

Tags: python

Given an input, How do I convert to ouput: List to Tupled numbers in Python 2/3

Input:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: Awesome! Found the answer in the post >>> zip(l,l[1:])[::2]

Comment: Or `list(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))`